Accessing healthLabel in Edamam API
I am looking to search for recipes using Edamam's API using two criteria: ingredient and dietary requirement. This is my code but it doesn't seem to work as it only seems to give me results based on ingredients. How can I fix it?
import requests

def recipe_search(ingredient):
# Register to get an APP ID and key https://developer.edamam.com/
    app_id = ''
    app_key = ''
    result = requests.get(
    'https://api.edamam.com/search?q={}&app_id={}&app_key={}'.format(ingredient, app_id, app_key)
)

    data = result.json()
    return data['hits']

def run():
    ingredient = input('Enter an ingredient: ')
    healthLabels = input('Enter a dietary requirement: ')
    results = recipe_search(ingredient)

    for result in results:
        recipe = result['recipe']
        healthLabels = recipe['healthLabels']

        if healthLabels == healthLabels:
            print(recipe['label'])
            print(recipe['url'])

        else:
            print("No Result")

run()

